# A unique solution for $y'=\cos\left(y\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've considered the non-linear problem
$$ \displaystyle \left(\star\right) \ \ \ \ \begin{cases}
\displaystyle y'(x)=\cos\left(y(x)\right)\\
y(0)=\alpha, \ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$$
I want to prove that it admits a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$. I've used the following lemma :

> **Grönwall Lemma :** If $y$ satisfies for all $t \in \left[0,+\infty\right[$ the inequality
>   $$
> y'\left(t\right) \leq \beta\left(t\right)y\left(t\right)
> $$
>   then for all $t \in \left[0,+\infty\right[$
>   $$
> y\left(t\right) \leq y\left(0\right) \text{exp}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\beta\left(s\right)\text{d}s\right)
> $$

Then let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two solutions of $(\star)$ then we have
$$
(y_1-y_2)'=\cos\left(y_1\left(t\right)\right)-\cos\left(y_2\left(t\right)\right)=-2\sin\left(\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y_1-y_2}{2}\right)
$$
So letting $Y=(y_1-y_2)/2$ we have
$$
Y' \leq \sin\left(\frac{y_1\left(t\right)+y_2\left(t\right)}{2}\right)\sin\left(-Y\right)
$$
Using that $Y\left(0\right)=0$, we have
$$
y_1(t)-y_2(t) \leq 0
$$
I can then use the same argument with $Z=y_2-y_1$ to obtain $y_2(t)-y_1(t) \leq 0$ to have
$$
y_1=y_2
$$
Can somebody tell me if it's true ( or correct me to fill the proof )? My problem is the majoration of $Y'$ because I dont know the sign of the sin ( can't be maxed by $1$ then ), and it depends on $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: How do you know that there exists such a solution on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because I've found it

Comment: If you have found a global solution, then the conclusion follows from [Picard existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), or known as Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem. However you don't need to know the solution because a stronger version of the theorem (mentioned in lonza's answer) applies as well.

Comment: I dont want to use this theorem but to complete the proof this way :/

Answer (score 1):

Since the function $\ \cos\ $ satisfies the Lipschitz condition $\ \mid\ \cos\left(y_2\right)-
\cos\left(y_2\right)\mid\ \le\  \mid y_1 - y_2\,\mid$ for all $\ y_1, y_2\in\mathbb R\ $, the existence and uniqueness of a solution follows from the [global Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem).